# Why is there a space between my hero and about section when I resize the height of the page?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I am fairly new at making responsive css and I have not done much yet.
If you open the following code in fullscreen and change the height of the tab, the smaller the height, the more of a gap there is between my hero and about section.
I want the gap to remain the same size on all devices.
Hopefully you can help,
Thanks.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#header {
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: -0.8%;
  background-image: url(./images/DJI_0410-Enhanced.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right;
  width: 98.5%;
  height: 94%;
}

#title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: 8%;
}

h1 {
  color: #f7f4f7;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font-size: 4.5vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#subTitle {
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3.6vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

button {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 7.5rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bookNow {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #2B3758;
  margin-right: 0.4rem;
  transition: 200ms linear;
  border: none;
}

.bookNow:hover {
  background-color: #e6e3e6;
  color: #2B3758;
}

.learnMore {
  background-color: #2B3758;
  color: #f7f4f7;
  margin-left: 0.4rem;
  transition: 200ms linear;
  border: none;
}

.learnMore:hover {
  background-color: #4e6090;
  color: #f7f4f7;
}

#navBar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 2% 8% 0% 8%;
}

.logo {
  width: 18%;
  height: 18%;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.page {
  color: white;
}

.otherPages {
  color: #585858;
  transition: 200ms linear;
}

.otherPages:hover {
  color: white;
}

.bookNow {
  margin-right: 8%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav__links {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav__links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.bookNowNav {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2.5px solid white;
  padding: 0px;
  transition: 200ms linear;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.bookNowNav:hover {
  background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.5);
}

#about {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 860px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 82.5%;
}

#aboutImage {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(./images/DJI_0216.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 47.8%;
  height: 475px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

#aboutInfo {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 47.8%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-top: -38px;
}

h2 {
  position: justify;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.info {
  color: rgb(140, 140, 140);
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  height: 240px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
  <title>Above Photography</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="header" class="center">

    <div id="navBar">

      <img class="logo" src="./images/AbovePhotographyLogo.png" alt="Logo">

      <nav>

        <ul class=n av__links>

          <li><a class="page" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="otherPages" href="#">Photography</a></li>
          <li><a class="otherPages" href="#">Videography</a></li>
          <li><a class="otherPages" href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <a href="#"><button class = "bookNowNav">Book Now</button></a>

        </ul>

      </nav>



    </div>

    <div id="title">

      <h1>Above <br>Photography</h1>
      <h2 id="subTitle">Taking The<br>Perfect Picture</h2>
      <button class="bookNow">Book Now</button>
      <button class="learnMore">Learn More</button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="about">

    <div id="aboutImage"></div>

    <div id="aboutInfo">

      <h2 class="">
        About
      </h2>

      <p class="info">
        My name is Max Herczeg and I'm a Grade 8 student from Toronto, Ontario. I have been flying drones for over 4 years and I've taken several photography courses as well. My passion for both of these interests has led me to create Above Photography. My age
        allows me to provide clients with an affordable cost for a high-end final product. Above Photography has a creative and fun approach to each project. My company uses the high-end DJI Air 2S Drone. It shoots 5.4K video resolution and 20 mega pixel
        pictures. This means that both photos and videos will look outstanding.
      </p>

      <button class="seeWork">Learn More</button>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Because your About section has a large, fixed `margin-top`.

Comment: What alternative can I use?

Comment: I'm not sure. There are a number of, lets say, unusual CSS choices in this code which prevent it from being adjusted easily.

Answer (score 0):

*Like mentioned by Ouroborus in the comments,* there is no short answer here and there are several reasons:

1. You’re setting both the header (`.center`) and the `#about` divs to `position: absolute`.

Absolute positioning removes elements from the normal document flow and has several side effects.

2. Your header’s height is set to a percentage value & it has no relative positioned parent container with a set height.  So it gets its height from the `<body>`, which at the same time is your **viewport**’s height.
   In other words, if your viewport changes height, so does your `#header` too.
3. You're setting a fixed `margin-top: 860px` to the `#about` section, but your `#header` dimensions are not fixed, like explained in point 2.

So putting it all together this means that whenever you make the viewport anything shorter than `860px`, the margin on the about section remains at 860px BUT your header shrinks with the viewport. Thus why *the shorter the height, the larger the gap in between*. This is how It works.

Note: If you make your window taller, because the header is 94% height of the body, it will actually overlap the about section. *You can see this clearly by setting a `background-color` to the `#header` and making your window 1600px tall for example.
 Also, when you do this, *as is* your `#title` will be centered vertically in the document... Potentially being out of place with your header's content and/or even overlapping with the about image (or any other content).

My suggestion is:

- Move away from position absolute unless strictly necessary for *complex* **inner** layouts. You don't need the header container or the about to be absolute.
- Before trying to do responsive layouts, make sure you understand how CSS `box-model`, `display`, and `position`works.. As well as flexbox and/or grid layouts (Even floats, if you want to learn like in the old days).

https://www.w3schools.com/css/ is a great place to start. Happy coding.